# Code PDF friendly HTML page from a Word Document

Tags: html, css, pdf, html-to-pdf

I have a word document file which I need to convert into HTML page that will be used by Ruby on Rail developers, it's a report file which will be converted into PDF later on. My question is what rules should I follow to make a PDF friendly html page so that it don't loose any styling or structure don't break after converting in PDF.

Comment: use inline-styles (highly recommended)

Comment: @Viira can I use internal css in <head> tag and what about images ?

Comment: Use full website link url as image

Comment: of course you can use <head> for styles